# Vuejs - made a component combogrid that can be clone but first row input text become empty after cloning a new one row

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

`The Html-`

```
<td class="left-align-column input-text-td" v-show="doc.is_edit" style="width:120px;">
  <doc-combogrid 
    style="width:150px;" 
    v-bind:key="docCombogridKey"
    ref="doc_po_find"
    v-model="doc.doc_id"
    v-bind:is-edit="doc.is_edit"
    v-bind:trans_ty="trans_ty"
    v-on:temp-code-name="doc.person = $event"
    ></doc-combogrid>
</td>
```

`The vue component-`

```
Vue.component('doc-combogrid', {
  template: `<div>
                        <input ref="doc_po_find" type="text" style="width:90%;">
                    </div>`,
  props: ['trans_ty'],
  mounted: function() {
    this.setupComboGrid();
  },

  methods: {
    setupComboGrid() {
      t_ty = this.trans_ty;
      let instance = this;
      $(this.$refs.doc_po_find).combogrid({
        alternate: true,
        navbar: false,
        searchIcon: true,
        draggable: true,
        minLength: 1,
        width: '50%',
        position: {
          my: "left top",
          at: "left bottom",
          collision: "none"
        },
        url: "index.php?r=fmform/Lookup&type=docpo&ty=" + t_ty,
        colModel: [{
            'columnName': 'doc_no',
            'width': '20',
            'align': 'left',
            'label': 'PO #'
          },
          {
            'columnName': 'supplier_name',
            'width': '50',
            'align': 'left',
            'label': 'Person Name'
          },
        ],
        select: function(event, ui) {

          this.value = ui.item.doc_no;
          instance.$emit('input', ui.item.doc_id);
          instance.$emit('temp-code-name', ui.item.supplier_name);
          return false;
        },
      });
    },
  },
});
```

`The cloning part in Vue-`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      newDoc: {
        id: null,
        doc_id: null,
        is_edit: true,
      },
      docCombogridKey: 1,
    }
  },
  addNewDoc() {
    let record = _.clone(this.newDoc);
    this.docList.unshift(record);
    this.docCombogridKey++;
    record.is_edit = true;
  },
  });
</script>
```

The first clone action was good-

[image]

But if I create a second clone before saving the data, the first-row input box becomes empty-

[image]

I try console.log to see if the data was there, its good, only the input was clear when the second clone was made, what did I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

Your `doc.doc_id` value it not bound in the component. The input value is not tracked by Vue reactivity automatically.

You have to bind the `input` in your component using `v-model`

```
<input type="text" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" />
```

Check the Vue 2 Docs on [Customizing Component v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model)

### Playground

```js
Vue.component('doc-combogrid', {
  template: `<div><input ref="doc_po_find" type="text" style="width:90%;" 
    :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" /></div>`,
  props: ['value'],
  event: ['input'],
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      trans_ty: {},
      docList: [],
      newDoc: {
        doc_id: null,
      },
      docCombogridKey: 1,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addNewDoc() {
      let record = _.clone(this.newDoc);
      this.docList.unshift(record);
      this.docCombogridKey++;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
<table>
<tr v-for="doc in docList">
  <td class="left-align-column input-text-td" style="width:120px;">
    <doc-combogrid
      style="width:150px;" 
      v-bind:key="docCombogridKey"
      ref="doc_po_find"
      v-model="doc.doc_id"   
      ></doc-combogrid>
  </td>
</tr>  
</table>  
<button @click="addNewDoc()">Add</button><hr/>
{{docList}}
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```